# Subscribe works but still shows errors?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created an app that retrieves documents assigned to a user. I can successfully retrieve the details of a given document id using:

```
this.http.post(API_URL,{id: id, token: TOKEN}).subscribe((res:Response) => this.document = res['data']);
```

And in the view component I correctly display the name of the retrieved document using:

```
{{ document.name }}
```

However, in the console I can see at least 3 errors that read:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

Is this something related to the timing of the response from the server?

Comment: It's because `post` is async, so at first the `document` is undefined. You can use the null safe operator in your template to remove this error: `{{ document?.name}}`, which will do the null check for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As because you are making a async operation, you should always make a check in your template. Something like:

```
<div *ngIf="document">
  {{ document.name }}
</div>
```

Or you can use a null safe operator

```
{{ document?.name }}
```